# How to update 'bot.users.size' in bot status without restarting

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

So basically I want my bot to have a dynamic status that changes every 5 seconds and displays how many users my bot is currently helping. The changing status part is not the issue, the problem is the users helped count does not change without restarting my bot, which is not ideal considering it is hosted and on many servers, no point restarting all the time just for the user count to be accurate.

What I have tried is by including a interval timer that will update the userCount variable in an attempt to make it accurate to how many users it is helping. What seems to be happening is when a user joins the server, the variable will update accordingly and display +1 in relation to the previous number of users helped. But, when a user leaves, it does not subtract one from the count, instead, it just leaves it at the previous count. I included `console.log(userCount)` just to make it easier to see the number every 10 seconds in the console, instead of having to wait for the bot's status to change to the proper one.

```js
bot.on('ready', function() {
    let userCount = bot.users.size
        setInterval(() => {
            userCount = bot.users.size
            console.log(userCount)
        }, 10000);
    setInterval(async () => {
    let statuslist = [
        'blah',
        "blah'",
        'blah ' + ` ${userCount} Users` 
    ];      
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * statuslist.length);

  try {
    await bot.user.setPresence({
      game: {
        name: `${statuslist[random]}`,
        type: "Playing"
      },
      status: "online"
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}, 5000);
console.log("Logged in as " + bot.user.username);
});
```

I feel as though this isn't a library issue, because I am not very confident in my ability to create code that checks for changes. Ideally, it will display the accurate number based on users joining/leaving servers the bot is on, as well as guilds inviting/removing the bot from the guild. I am not sure if I should use events for this, and even if I was to, I do not know how I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But, when a user leaves, it does not subtract one from the count, instead, it just leaves it at the previous count.

This is expected of `client.users`. It's a collection of all the users the client has cached at some point, so it shouldn't remove any. I think what you're looking for is this...

```js
bot.on('ready', () => {
  setInterval(async () => {
    let users = 0;
    for (let g of bot.guilds.array()) users += (g.members.size - 1));

    await bot.user.setActivity(`${users} user${users !== 1 ? 's' : ''}`, {type: 'WATCHING'})
    .catch(err => console.error());
  }, 15000);
});
```

Note that this will count users over again if they're in 2 guilds. If you'd rather have a precise count, at the cost of memory, you could use...

```js
bot.on('ready', () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    let guilds = bot.guilds.array();
    let users = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < guilds.length; i++) {
      let members = guilds[i].members.array();

      for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
        if (members[i].user.id !== bot.user.id && users.indexOf(members[i].user.id) === -1) users.push(members[i].user.id);
      }
    }

    bot.user.setActivity(`${users.length} user${users.length !== 1 ? 's' : ''}`, {type: 'WATCHING'})
    .catch(err => console.error());
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! With a little tweaking it is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 setIntervals, combine them! 
That should solve your issue.

You could also use the `guildMemberAdd` / `guildMemberRemove` event.

```
bot.on('ready', function() {
    setInterval(async () => {
        const statuslist = [
            'blah',
            'blah_1',
            ` ${bot.users.size} Users`,
        ];
        console.log(statuslist);
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * statuslist.length);

        try {
            await bot.user.setPresence({
                game: {
                    name: `${statuslist[random]}`,
                    type: 'Playing',
                },
                status: 'online',
            });
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }, 15000);
    console.log('Logged in as ' + bot.user.username);
});
```